# Use Clearfsimport within a tcl exec command

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, clearcase

I am using `clearfsimport` to recursively check a file tree into clearcase. From everything ive read it seems to be the best way however when I run the command `exec clearfsimport -rec -nset create_clearcase_tempfile/* .` inside of a `tcl` script I receive the following error;

```
Validating directory ".".
Closing directories.
No change in version "/main/91" of directory "."
clearfsimport: Error: Could not access "create_clearcase_tempfile/*".
```

My suspicion is that the `/*` confuses the command but when I try it outside of tcl directly in the bash commands it works exactly as expected. Can someone please tell me what im missing?

Comment: Tcl's exec does not invoke a shell, so '*' is not interpreted.

Comment: is there an equivalent to the `*` wildcare but for a tcl `exec` commant? or is my only option to make a loop that handles each file case by case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that (unlike bash) Tcl does not expand file globs by default; it just passes the `*` on over, and ClearCase gets surprised by that. You probably want to change:

```
exec clearfsimport -rec -nset create_clearcase_tempfile/* .
```

to this:

```
exec clearfsimport -rec -nset {*}[glob create_clearcase_tempfile/*] .
```

Comment: When I try that I get the message `invalid command name "create_clearcase_tempfile/*"` I am using tcl version 8.6

Comment: @LiamP You remember to use `glob` in there? It's important.

Comment: Wow now it seems so simple... Thanks I am relatively new at tcl and still learning how to properly work recursively.

Comment: Tcl's exec has a lot of magic, but not expanding globs is a good idea.